# CodeIgniter: format mysql DATETIME field dd/mm/yy hh:mm

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter, date-format

Hi pretty much what it says on the tin.

I have a datetime mysql field I want to output in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm like 07/01/2011 22:16.

I've tried:

```
<?php 
  $datestring = '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i';  
  echo mdate($datestring,$row->created); 
?>
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Any help most appreciated!

Cheers,

Billy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
echo date ("d/m/Y h:ia",strtotime($row->created));
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the `mdate()` function still needs to be an integer timestamp, just like the native PHP `date()` function. Try using the `strtodate()` function which accepts a string as a parameter (including the MySQL date format) and returns an integer. This can be done like this:

```
$datestring = '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i';
echo mdate($datestring, strtodate($row->created));
```

The only difference between `mdate()` and `date()` is, as the CodeIgniter docs say:

> This function is identical to PHPs date() function, except that it lets you use MySQL style date codes, where each code letter is preceded with a percent sign: %Y %m %d etc.
>
> The benefit of doing dates this way is that you don't have to worry about escaping any characters that are not date codes, as you would normally have to do with the date() function.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work using treeface's solution, with one minor change:

```
$datestring = '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i';
echo mdate($datestring, strtoDATE($row->created)); 
    //strtoDATE didn't work but strtoTIME did
```

Had me scratching my head for hours, but now it works, I'm able to keep using CI helper for all date functions.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

I'm using:

```
mdate(date_string,mysql_to_unix($row->created))
```

That should work.